# ¿Cómo pasar información de variables a una class php?

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiente variable:

```
$user_code
```

La misma que trae información de una consulta, esta tiene el siguiente dato `USR7J`

Ahora esa información deseo pasarla una `class` de `PHP` no estoy tan familiarizado pero intento lo siguiente:

```
class generatePDF {

    public $code_user; //variable con datos desde la base de datos

    public function GenerateBarcode($AuthorizeKey) {
        $colorFront = new BCGColor(0, 0, 0);
        $colorBack = new BCGColor(255, 255, 255);
        $code = new BCGcode128();
        $code->setScale(4);
        $code->setThickness(30);
        $code->setForegroundColor($colorFront);
        $code->setBackgroundColor($colorBack);
        $code->parse($AuthorizeKey);

        $drawing = new BCGDrawing('user/' . $this->code_user . '/' . 'codigo.png', $colorBack);
        $drawing->setBarcode($code);

        $drawing->draw();

        $drawing->finish(BCGDrawing::IMG_FORMAT_PNG);
    }

    public function invoicePDF($document, $AuthorizeKey) {
            $this->GenerateBarcode($AuthorizeKey);
    }

}
```

Prácticamente lo que he intentado es guardar el código generado en la carpeta del usuario:

```
$drawing = new BCGDrawing('user/' . $this->code_user . '/' . 'codigo.png', $colorBack);
```

Pero dice que la variable no esta definida en conclusión la esta recibeindo nula ya que en vez de mostrar esto:

```
user/USR7J/codigo.png
```

Me muestra esto:

```
user//codigo.png
```

Que aparte del error de la variable no definida, me genere este error de `Failed to open stream: No such file or directory` y es porque el dato de la variable `$code_user` no la esta recibiendo.

¿Cómo puedo pasar esta variable a una `class` de `PHP` y poder usarla en cualquier parte de la `class` `generatePDF`?

Comment: ¿donde inicializas la instancia del objeto de esa clase?  Ponlo en la pregunta (es decir, busca algo asi como `$variable = new generatePDF();`)

Comment: @masterguru La verdad soy nuevo en esto, solo quiero hacer funcionar una librería :(

Comment: @masterguru y no he manejado programación orientada a objetos solo de la manera normal simple

Comment: Pero si te dice que la variable no está definida es porque estás usando esa clase en algun momento... por eso preguntaba como la inicializabas, pues para llegar a ese error debes usarla de algun modo.  ¿Como lo haces? ¿como invocas a esa clase para que aparezca ese error?

Comment: @masterguru Ya he leído la documentación he intentado lo siguiente https://ideone.com/rb5fcu pero nada como lo simple que sería `function nombre(){}` y para imprimir `echo nombre();`

Comment: @masterguru ese es todo mi código yo pensé que al agregar esto `public $code_user;` funcionaría dentro de toda la `class` pero no y, la llamo de la siguiente manera la `class` `$facturaPDF = new generatePDF();
$facturaPDF->facturaPDF($dataComprobante, $AuthorizeKey);`

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta que acabo de poner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparte de la buena respuesta de Julio, existe otra forma para conseguir lo que pretendes, que seria así:

```
$facturaPDF = new generatePDF();
$facturaPDF->code_user = $user_code;
$facturaPDF->facturaPDF($dataComprobante, $AuthorizeKey);
```

Eso suponiendo que la variable $user_code ya está predefinida antes de usarse, claro.

### Explicación

Cuando haces esto:

```
$facturaPDF = new generatePDF();
```

estas instanciando un objeto de la clase `generatePDF()` en una variable denominada `$facturaPDF`.

Dicha variable hereda todas las propiedades y métodos (en una clase las funciones se denominan métodos, pero vienen a ser lo mismo, ningun misterio) de la clase.

El error que tu tenias era porque te faltaba definir la propiedad `code_user` de tu instancia antes de llamar al método `facturaPDF()`, por lo tanto lo que hacemos, y sabiendo que el valor que le quieres dar ya lo tienes en una variable global denominada `$user_code`, es simplemente realizar la asignación de este modo:

```
$facturaPDF->code_user = $user_code;
```

Y ahora sí que teoricamente evitarás el error que comentas en tu pregunta cuando realices la llamada al método de este modo:

```
$facturaPDF->facturaPDF($dataComprobante, $AuthorizeKey);
```

Es probable que surgan otros errores por otras causas quizás, pero el actual que has preguntado no debería aparecer más.

Comment: Ahora mismo lo intento!!

Comment: esto funciono de maravillas, gracias :)

Comment: Bien, me alegro :-)  Léete la explicación para ir perdiendo el miedo a las clases!

Comment: seguro ese es mi próximo paso aprenderlas :)

Answer (score 1):

Para poder usar la variable dentro de la clase podes usar el constructor, pasarla como parámetro al método que la necesite o declararla como global en el método en que sea requerida.

Para usar el constructor (`__construct`), debes establecer quién la recibe, algo así como:

```
class mi_clase {
    var $mi_variable;

    function __construct($mi_var) { $this->mi_variable = $mi_var; }

    ... todo el resto del código ....
```

Si la pasas como parámetro al método:

```
function mi_metodo($mi_var)
```

O si la declaras global:

```
function mi_metodo() {
    global $variable_definida_fuera_de_la_clase;
```

Cada forma tiene unas implicaciones diferentes. Te invito a leer el alcance de las variables: [Variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: no entendí , lo siento... Esta más difícil que en la documentación de `PHP` cuando he intentado lo siguiente: https://ideone.com/rb5fcu

Comment: Tenes 3 formas de usar una variable definida fuera de una clase: se la pasas como parámetro cuando instancias el objeto, se la pasas como parámetro cuando llamas al método, o la definis como `global` dentro del método donde la necesites. PHP tiene un manual fenomenal y unos aportes de usuario increíbles.